# DirectAccess client (Windows 8.1 Ent) unable to connect to DirectAccess server (Server 2012)

Tags: direct-access

This is my first time setting up a DirectAccess Server. I've completed the wizard on the server& everything is completed & running without errors. My laptop is unable to connect successfully. I can see the Network name, but it remains in "connecting" state.

As part of troubleshooting, I modified a few steps in the wizard, name the Network name. The my laptop can still only need to original DA Network name, but not the new one. I should note that I've never been able to successfully connect.

It's configured with a separate NLS server, which can be contacted from the DA server. The DA server uses a single network adaptor.

**Netsh interface httpstunnel show interface** shows error code 0x0 & the interface is active.
I get a **NameResolutionFailure** for **DA-ConnectionStatus**
**Netsh dnsclient show state** shows DirectAccess and **configured & enabled**, with the client outside the corporate network

Below is the output of the DA Client Troubleshooter. I'm literally all of ideas with regards to troubleshooting. It's probably something obvious I'm missing, but any help would be appreciated

```
[23/02/2015 10:48:45]: Running Inside/Outside location tests.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:48:45]: NLS is hxxps://nls.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.local/.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:48:46]: NLS is not reachable via HTTPS, the client computer is not connected to the corporate network (external) or the NLS is offline.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:48:46]: NRPT contains 2 rules.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:48:46]:   Found (unique) DNS server: fdcd:c700:98ec:3333::1<br>
[23/02/2015 10:48:46]:   Send an ICMP message to check if the server is reachable.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:48:58]: DNS Server fdcd:c700:98ec:3333::1 does not reply on ICMP Echo requests.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:48:58]: Running IP connectivity tests.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:04]: The 6to4 interface is disabled.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:04]: Teredo inferface status is offline.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:04]:  The configured DirectAccess Teredo server is win8.ipv6.microsoft.com..<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:04]: The IPHTTPS interface is operational.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:04]:  The IPHTTPS interface status is IPHTTPS interface active.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:04]: IPHTTPS is used as IPv6 transition technology.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:04]:  The configured IPHTTPS URL is hxxps://directa.xxxxxxxxxx.com:443.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:04]: IPHTTPS has a single site configuration.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:04]: IPHTTPS URL endpoint is: hxxps://directa.xxxxxxxxxx.com:443.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:05]:  Successfully connected to endpoint hxxps://directa.xxxxxxxxxx.com:443.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:05]: No response received from xxxxxxxxxx.local.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:05]: Running Windows Firewall tests.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:05]: The current profile of the Windows Firewall is Public.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:05]: The Windows Firewall is enabled in the current profile Public.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:06]: The outbound Windows Firewall rule Core Networking - Teredo (UDP-Out) is enabled.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:06]: The outbound Windows Firewall rule Core Networking - IPHTTPS (TCP-Out) is enabled.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:06]: Running certificate tests.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:06]: Found 1 machine certificates on this client computer.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:06]: Checking certificate CN=xxxxx-xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.local with the serial number [5BC7E01767145B8E403BF44D3234AFD6].<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:06]:  The certificate [5BC7E01767145B8E403BF44D3234AFD6] contains the EKU Client Authentication.<br>
[23/02/2015 10:49:06]:  The trust chain for the certificate [5BC7E01767145B8E403BF44D3234AFD6] was sucessfully verified.<br>
```